# Функция Sleep в запросе

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужнo чтобы SQL запрос выполнялся определённое время. Написал функцию:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.TEST_SLEEP (TIME_ IN  NUMBER)
RETURN INTEGER IS
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOCK.sleep(seconds => TIME_);
RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
    RETURN 1;
END TEST_SLEEP;
```

и вызываю её так:

```
SELECT TEST_SLEEP(10.5) FROM DUAL
```

Но для того, чтобы она работала нужен `grant` на `DBMS_LOCK`.

Как можно переписать функцию без использования `DBMS_LOCK.sleep`?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/2561671/6571020

Answer (score 2):

Можно восользоваться методом `Thread.sleep`, для которого остаётся только создать простую  обёрточную функцию:

```sql
create or replace function sleep (milliseconds in number) return char deterministic is
language java name 'java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) return char';
/
```

И вызывать её так:

```sql
select sleep (1000) from dual;
```

или так:

```sql
exec -
    dbms_output.put_line ('t1 '||systimestamp); -
    if sleep (1000) is null then null; end if; -
    dbms_output.put_line ('t2 '||systimestamp);

Elapsed: 00:00:01.515
t1 2019-09-21 13:31:10,354367000 +02:00
t2 2019-09-21 13:31:11,356431000 +02:00
```

<sub>[Идея @dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657087/6571020)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

В релизе 18c появилась процедура [DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_SESSION.html#GUID-27CCC2F7-6564-41D2-8C42-CFFBF25A69B5):

> This procedure suspends the session for a specified period of time.
>
> ```
> DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP (seconds  IN NUMBER)
> ```

`DBMS_SESSION.sleep` доступна для любой сессии без дополнительных привелегий.
Возьмите на заметку: `DBMS_LOCK.sleep` объявлена устаревшей (deprecated).

Вызов в запросе будет выглядеть так:

```sql
with function sleep (sec number) return varchar2 is
begin
    dbms_session.sleep (sec);
    return 'woken after '||sec||' sec.';
end;
select sleep(3) q from dual
/

Q
-----------------------
woken after 3 sec.
```

<sub>[Идея @LukaszSzozda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49077572/6571020)</sub>